# Display multiple <p:graphicImage> on one page

Tags: java, image, jsf, primefaces

This is a simplified fragment of a larger software. I have a problem with displaying images using p: grapicImage. I want to display images consecutively after “Paste” of each. In general, external graphics is copied and converted by a utility class into DefaultStreamedContent and *.png files, the latter residing in resource/images folder. Using DefaultStreamedContent, when I click the first paste, it shows correctly Image 1 but when I click the second paste, Image 2 shows up and Image 1 disappears and, when I click the third paste, Image 3 shows up but Image 2 also disappears.
Using *.png files, the first paste does not show any images, the second paste shows Image 1 but not image 2 and the third paste shows image 2 and Image 1 but not Image 3. Finally, I can see all images if I click web page reload button after the third paste.
The attached xhtml file contains active display of *.png files.
I tried a variety of approaches including update= various segments, noting that many people had problems with p:grapicImage, and I did not find a remedy. My questions are: why the code behaves this way and how I can make it work properly.

The display of images using the code:

[image]

```
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>

<body>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css" />

    <h:form id="weeklyupdate">
        <p:layout id="panel1" style="width:1240px; height:880px;">

            <p:layoutUnit styleClass="layout" position="center">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:1200px">
                    <p:layout style="width:600px; height:840px;">
                        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                            <p:commandButton value="Paste 1" 
                                actionListener="#{weeklyProjectsUI.pasteImageWork}" ajax="false" />

                            <p:graphicImage id="imgwork" url="resources/images/work.png"
                                style="width: 570px; min-height:25%" cache="false" />

                            <ui:remove>
                                <p:graphicImage id="imgwork" styleClass="imagedisplay"
                                    value="#{weeklyProjectsUI.imageWork}"
                                    style="width: 570px; min-height:25%" cache="false" />
                            </ui:remove>
                        </p:layoutUnit>
                    </p:layout>
                    <p:layout style="width:600px; height:840px;">
                        <p:layoutUnit styleClass="layout" position="center">
                            <br></br>

                            <p:commandButton value="Paste 2"
                                actionListener="#{weeklyProjectsUI.pasteImageEvidence1}"
                                ajax="false" />

                            <p:graphicImage id="imgevidence1" styleClass="imagedisplay"
                                url="resources/images/evidence1.png"
                                style="width: 570px; min-height:25%" cache="false" />


                            <ui:remove>
                                <p:graphicImage styleClass="imagedisplay"
                                    value="#{weeklyProjectsUI.imageEvidence1}"
                                    style="width: 570px; min-height:25%" cache="false" />
                            </ui:remove>

                            <br></br>
                            <br></br>

                            <p:commandButton value="Paste 3"
                                actionListener="#{weeklyProjectsUI.pasteImageEvidence2}"
                                ajax="false" />

                            <ui:remove>
                                <p:graphicImage styleClass="imagedisplay"
                                    value="#{weeklyProjectsUI.imageEvidence2}"
                                    style="width: 570px; min-height:25%" cache="false" />
                            </ui:remove>

                            <p:graphicImage id="imgevidenc2" styleClass="imagedisplay"
                                url="resources/images/evidence2.png"
                                style="width: 570px; min-height:25%" cache="false" />

                        </p:layoutUnit>
                    </p:layout>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>
    </h:form>
</body>

</html>
```

..and the essential part of the backing bean

```
    public void pasteImageWork() throws IOException{

    String work = "work";
    imageService.imageCopy(work);
    loadImageWork();
}

public void pasteImageEvidence1() throws IOException {

    String evidence1 ="evidence1";
    imageService.imageCopy(evidence1);
    loadImageEvidence1();
}

public void pasteImageEvidence2() throws IOException {

    String evidence2="evidence2";
    imageService.imageCopy(evidence2);
    loadImageEvidence2();

}

public void loadImageWork() throws IOException{

    imageWork = imageService.getGraphicImage();
    System.out.println("Work loaded: " + imageWork.toString());

}

public void loadImageEvidence1() throws IOException {

    imageEvidence1 = imageService.getGraphicImage();
    System.out.println("Evidence1 loaded: " + imageEvidence1.toString());

}

public void loadImageEvidence2() throws IOException {

    imageEvidence2 = imageService.getGraphicImage();
    System.out.println("Evidence2 loaded: " + imageEvidence2.toString());

}
```

By the way, I am using primefaces 5.3. with eclipse.

Comment: It seems that my question is difficult to answer even by experts and I am not surprised because, in my opinion, it may be impossible to figure it without knowing well the JQuery code behind graphicImage. There is probably http request or requests that take only last created StreamedContent and skip other StreamedContent variables stored in the memory. I am wondering if there is a possibility to look at the jQuery source code of graphicImage to figure out what can be done with this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution I have chosen involves a display of each image on a separate web page (tab), each created with a UI layer bean method using DefaultStreamedContent , as shown in the example below:

```
   public void loadImageWork() throws IOException {
    imageWork = imageService.getGraphicImage();
    imageWorkName = imageWork.getName();
    streamWork = imageService.getOs();
 RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open('weeklyWork.xhtml')");
```

Os is here ByteArrayOutputStream.

All images can be next transferred at once to SQL Server filestream storage as required.